# npm: How to install all dependencies at once

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, lint, eslint

I installed `eslint` and when running command `npm run lint` then every time it asks to install all dependencies one by one. Is there any command option to install all once rather than running `npm run lint` all the time?

`package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "laravel-elixir-livereload": "1.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "4.1.1",
    "eslint": "1.3.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "0.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "3.3.1",
    "laravel-elixir-eslint": "1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "3.2.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.5",
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint resources/assets/js/"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `package.json`.

Comment: @AdrianLynch Question updated

Comment: `npm install eslint` should install all dependencies for you, are you sure the install command isn't failing somehow? Could you give us an example of the output you are seeing? Also, you don't need to preface npm script entries with `./node_modules/.bin/eslint`, you can just use `eslint`

Comment: How about your Gupl file? Maybe create a new repo with only eslint and a test file. See what happens.

Comment: Can you include the exact wording you are being prompted with? Is it a version conflict (is it asking you to pick among various versions of a dependency)?

Answer (score -1):

use npm install , It will read the top of your gulpfile an install all dependencies listed